# Probability of working shifts

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 35 shifts in a week. None of the shifts overlap. There are 5 shifts for each day of the week. I must work exactly 9 shifts per week. My boss randomly picks 9 shifts for me to work. Each shift is equally likely.

What's the probability of working at least 1 shift on each day of the week?

My thoughts:
All shifts are distinct. I think there are $\binom{35}{9}$ outcomes. It will probably be easier to use complementary counting where 1 - (the outcomes where I don't work a shift each day). But I'm stuck on what to do next. Any answers/help are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are $35$ shifts and you work $9$ of them, so indeed there are a total of $\binom{35}9$ outcomes. Now, consider your first seven shifts to be distributed among the seven days of the week - there are $5^7$ ways these could be distributed. You have two remaining shifts; either these are on the same day, or two different days. If they are on the same day, then there are $\binom 61 \binom 42$ ways these can be distributed. If they are on different days, then there are $\binom 62 \binom 41$ ways these can be distributed. Putting this together, you have a probability of
$$
\frac{5^7\left(\binom 61\binom42+\binom62\binom41\right)}{\binom{35}9} = 125000/1176791\approx 0.1062211
$$
probability of working at least one shift on each day of the week.